# Godaddy seal showing multiple times when clicked on browser back button?

Tags: image, browser

At the footer i have this code to display the godaddy seal

```
<footer class='text-center'>
<p>
<span id='siteseal'>
<script async src='https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=Nbs00qGadT8ILaxW12TDlYGkLLzafwt4TSDFmSljCQjDcdB0B1J02RveTAaZ'></script>
</span>
</p>
<p>
Copyright &copy; 2018
</p>
</footer>
```

The footer seal displays correctly. I click on few links and it again displays the seal once. But now when i click on back button of browser which takes to the origin page where i clicked on the link it will now show duplicate logo as shown below

[image]

If i am deeply nested and click on back more than once then it will keep duplicating the logo. If i click on back button three times then it displays three logos.

How can i fix this issue? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily add this CSS to hide the duplicated image:

```
#siteseal img + img { 
  display: none;
}
```

This won't resolve the issue, which is most likely a result of the JS getting loaded twice. Double check that the JS isn't included elsewhere on the page. A URL to site would also help.